# How to put the output query from mySQL to php int variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a query to get the last id (int) in a table to create a new row with that last id + 1 but actually this just put all rows with the same id

my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "dbpass";
$dbname = "site";
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sqlID = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM `login`;";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlID)) {
    $id = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
}

settype($id, "int");
$id = $id + 1;


$sql = "INSERT INTO login (`id`,`mail`,`password`)
             VALUES ('".$id."','".$mail."','".$password."');";



if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: Is id autoincrement?

Comment: no, id is not autoincrement

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Make `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT`. What you're doing here is going to cause severe trouble when you run into a race condition and have an `id` conflict. From the perspective of the computer a tiny eternity passes between getting your `MAX(id)` value and doing the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_row returns always an array, also if there is only 1 element. So the MAX(id) in in $row[0].

Fixing this, you also don't need to use settype.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about a lot of things, *especially* the type of a variable. It will auto-convert as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is autoincrement, change this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login (`id`,`mail`,`password`)
         VALUES ('".$id."','".$mail."','".$password."');";
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login (`mail`,`password`)
         VALUES ('".$mail."','".$password."');";
```

Then get rid of all code from `$sqlID` to `$id + 1;` (for tidyness)